# jquery Ajax cakephp: email not fetching and displaying corresponding name from database

Tags: cakephp, jquery

When the user enters his/her MerryParentEmail address, the corresponding name should be fetched fr the database and displayed in the MerryParentName input textbox. I have already tried doing this with ajax, jquery and php and it worked. But now, the corresponding name is not getting displayed when i use ajax, jquery and cakephp.

The alert outputs: data%5BMerryParent%5D%5Bemail%5D=b

Can someone point out on where i'm going wrong? Thank you.

default.ctp (layout file)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#MerryParentEmail").keyup(function(){
    //txt=$("#MerryParentEmail").val();
    txt=$("#MerryParentEmail").serialize();
    alert(txt);
    $.post("../merry_parents/getname",txt,function(result){
      $("#MerryParentName").val(result);  
    });
  });
});
 </script>
```

view.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash();
//echo $this->Form->create('MerryParent', array('default'=>false));
echo $this->Form->create('MerryParent');

echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Parent Information</legend>';
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.email');
/*if (isset($name))
   echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.name', array('label'=>'Parent/Guardian Name','value'=>$name));
else*/
   echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.name', array('label'=>'Parent/Guardian Name'));

echo '</fieldset>';

//echo $this->Form->end('Submit');

 ?>
```

merry_parents_controller.php

```
<?php
 class MerryParentsController extends AppController{
public $many_children_flag='false';
var $name='MerryParents';

function beforeFilter()//executed before any controller action logic
{   parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Security->validatePost=false;  //set to false to completely skip the validation of POST request
        //parent::beforeFilter();
    if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
        $this->Security->enabled = false;
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
        $this->autoRender=false;
        }   
}

function getname(){
 if (!empty($this->data)){
    //var_dump($this->data);

    $merryparent_info=$this->MerryParent->getMerryParents($this->data['MerryParent']['email']);
    //print_r($merryparent_info);
    $name=$merryparent_info['MerryParent']['name'];
    $this->set('name',$name);
    //$this->render('/merry_parents/ajax_input');
    }
}
function view(){
    //$name='';
    //var_dump($this->data);
    //$this->getname();
}
```

merry_parent.php model

```
function getMerryParents($field_value){
    if (is_int($field_value))
        $conditions=array('merryParent.id'=>$field_value);
    else
        $conditions=array('merryParent.email'=>$field_value);

    //debug($conditions);

    $merryparent_info=$this->find('first',array(
                                'conditions'=>$conditions,
                                'recursive'=>-1   //fetches merry_parents table data only not the associated data
                                ));

    //debug($merryparent_info);
    return $merryparent_info;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
//add
$this->layout = false;  
//and instead of setting name simply echo the name from your function, like
echo $name;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, that worked! :) But why $this->layout has to be set to false?

Comment: Glad to know that. Yes since its ajax and you dont need any layout in your case, so it should be set to false

Comment: I tried without setting $this->layout to false and it still works. By the way, it works only with keypress not keyup.